# Where can I find the soure code for /system/bin/service?

Tags: android

I would like to make an enhanced copy of /system/bin/service. Can someone link me or provide the directory where the source is?

I tried looking [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r48/cmds/) but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for /system/bin/service in Android can be found in the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) on GitHub. To access the code, you will need to clone the AOSP repository onto your local machine using Git. Once you have cloned the repository, you can navigate to the /system/bin/service directory to view the source code.

Comment: Well, where exactly? I don't see anything in the [repository](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).